# Set of "perfect" Numbers in quantor logic

Tags: logic, divisibility

Write $D=\{6,28\}$ as the set of perfect numbers which are bigger then 2 and smaller then 30.

$D=\{x\in\mathbb{N}:(2<x<30)\wedge (d_{1,2,...,i}\in(\{d\in\mathbb{N}:d|x\}\backslash\{x\}):d_1+d_2+\cdots+d_i=x)\}$

As a refresher: perfect numbers are numbers which are the sum of their devisors (except the number)

I feel $d_{1,2,...,i}$ is a little bit bad, how to write this?

Comment: For perfect, sum of divisors other than $n$ is $n$ or sum of all divisors is $2n$. I would write $\sum_{d\mid n}d=2n$.  Defining perfect in predicate calculus using say just addition and multiplication can be done, but is achieved with difficulty, and is very much beyond the level of your course.

Comment: Also, $1$ **is** counted as one of the divisors.  $6=1+2+3\neq 2+3$

Comment: oh,that's right, thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt reads poorly for a number of reasons.  $d_{1,2,\dots,i}\in (\{d\in\Bbb N~:~d\mid x\}\setminus \{x\})$ does not guarantee that $d_1,\dots,d_i$ are *all* of the divisors.  It could merely be a subset of them.

For example, $x=12$, you could have $2,4,6$ are all elements of $(\{d\in\Bbb N~:~d\mid x\}\setminus\{x\})$ and $2+4+6=12$, but we do not consider it to be a perfect number.  (It is instead what we call a [semiperfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiperfect_number))

You could remedy this by saying instead $\{d_1,d_2,\dots,d_i\} = (\{d\in\Bbb N~:~d\mid x\}\setminus \{x\})$ to guarantee that you are taking the set of *all* proper divisors of $x$.

As pointed out in the comments above, however, there is a much more compact method to write this out.  You have probably been exposed to one of the uses of summation notation in the past.  $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i = a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n$

You may also use sets or conditions to specify what terms are being summed.

$\sum\limits_{i\in\{3,7\}}i^2 = 3^2+7^2$.  Here we use values of $i$ for which the statement $i\in\{3,7\}$ is true and ignore all other values.

In this way, we can express the sum as $\sum\limits_{d\mid x} d$.  That is to say, for every value of $d$, if $d$ divides evenly into $x$ then we will add it, else we don't.

$\sum\limits_{d\mid 12} d = 1+2+3+4+6+12 = 28$ for example.

In order to account for the fact that $x$ divides $x$, we may either put the additional restriction that $d\neq x$ under the summation symbol: $\sum\limits_{d\mid x,~d\neq x}d=x$, or we may notice that if we allow for including $x$ as a divisor, the condition on perfect numbers is that instead the sum equals $2x$.

As such, a more compact and easily readable way to write your set is:

$$D = \{x\in\Bbb N~:~2<x<30,~\sum\limits_{d\mid x}d=2x\}$$